# Example of a divergent alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could you think of an example of an alternating series $a_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$?  
I wonder if something like this even exists. By definition, this statement would have to be true: 
$$\neg (a_1 \ge a_2 \ge ... )$$
But this does not go in pair with the fact that $a_n$ approaches zero.

Comment: You say "divergent" in the title, but ask for a converging sequence in the post itself. Which is it?

Comment: I asked for a divergent sequence such that, even though it is divergent, $\lim a_n = 0$

Comment: Do you mean a divergent series?

Comment: @JimmyR. 
I'm sorry. I have edited my post, it contained a typo in its body.

Comment: So, you want an alternating sequence $a_n$, such that $a_n\to0$ but $\sum a_n=\infty$? Right?

Comment: @JimmyR.  Yes, exactly

Comment: Ok, that is not what you have written.

Answer (score 4):

Note that because $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n\to 0$, the sum $\sum_{n= 0}^\infty a_n$ cannot fail to exist because the partial sums oscillate (or behave chaotically, or in any other bounded fashion), it *must* be because it tends to either positive or negative infinity. We can achieve this by making, say, the negative terms *much smaller* than the positive terms. For instance,
$$
a_n = \cases{\frac 1n & if $n$ is odd\\-2^{-n} & if $n$ is even}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the series $$\frac{1}{1^2}-\frac{1}{1} +\frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3^2} - \frac{1}{3} + \cdots$$ The terms alternate and go to $0$. However, this series is a divergent series and I will leave you to prove this for yourself (check the partial sums).